# Memory used by core i3 gpu

Tags: gpu, intel-core-i3

I have core i3 530 on Asus p7h55 pro and 2gb memory.
Windows shows 1.85gb. I think the remaining is used solely by the onchip gpu.

Can/how do i increase that amount and extract more graphic performance?

Answer (score 1):

> Can do i increase that amount and extract more graphic performance?

Increasing the memory allocated for a GPU has no bearing on the performance. The IGP's aren't very powerful, and adding extra memory won't be of any use.

Comment: aren't very powerful? I can lay aoe3 on full graphics without glitch.

Comment: there should be some way to change the size. BIOS has setting for 128M and 256M, but nothing beyond. and if memory has no bearing on GPU, why would gfx cards come with 1gb ddr5 ram??

Comment: @Mobiel AOE3 is hardly a game which is demanding on the GPU. Memory on GPU is used a frame buffer and to store textures. Higher quality textures == better detail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to use the ASUS utilities at your disposal?

[image]

I have one of their laptops and it makes managing overclocking a thoroughly easy task. I would recommend popping open the ASUS utility for your IGP and see what tweaks you can make. Although allocating more memory to the GP itself may not be your best bet, overclocking the IGP may be an option. (Sorry the link is to an -EVO instead of -PRO.)